# Bad file descriptor in Net::LDAP::Bind

Tags: perl, ldap, certificate, starttls

I am establishing the following LDAP connection with Net::LDAP:

```
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new( $ldap_host, version => 3 );
my $mesg = $ldap->start_tls(
    verify => 'none',
);

$mesg = $ldap->bind( $dn, password => $ldappass );
```

This will work, and even let me make a query later to check a user's credentials.
But if I try to verify server certificate:

```
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new( $ldap_host, version => 3 );
my $mesg = $ldap->start_tls(
    verify => 'require',
    cafile => '/var/certs/Certificate_Bundle.pem'
);

$mesg = $ldap->bind( $dn, password => $ldappass );
```

It will successfully establish the connection and <s>verify the server certificate</s>, but while trying the Bind operation I get the following LDAP message parameters:

```
    'resultCode' => 82,
    'pdu' => '0O`J3cn=foo1,ou=foo2,dc=foo3Passwd',
    'errorMessage' => 'Bad file descriptor'
```

I'm surprised because result code 82 is defined as LDAP_LOCAL_ERROR, but all the certificate bit seems to work. If I change the 'cafile' parameter to a wrong value, it will fail with a 'I/O Error Connection reset by peer' error message.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I just realized that the certificate verification was not being successful. The LDAP server was using other certificate than the one I had been told. I realized that by using openssl to monitor the handshaking process:

```
openssl s_client -connect *server:port* -showcerts -state
```

and there you can see the certificate that the server is effectively using.